# Entity Framework Returns No Value With MVC Action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm facing a problem with Entity Framework and MVC ActionResult returns Partial View.
I was create very sample code to retrieve data from database to partial view action, and plug data to partial view as normal data model.
But when I use the same code to retrieve data, it's not work and return empty model, and when I use it with the normal ActionResult that's return normal View it's work.

This is the Partial View action:

```
public ActionResult PaperSpecification()
{
    var _sheets = _entity.Sheets.ToList();

    return PartialView("_SheetSpecificationPartial", _sheets);
}
```

_entity variable defined as private in controller class.

The same idea I used to but in Index action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var _sheets = _entity.Sheets.ToList();

    return View(_sheets);
}
```

This is Index view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model IEnumerable<PrintManager.Models.Db.Sheet>
<h2>Index</h2>

@{
    Html.RenderAction("PaperSpecification", "WorkOrder");
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item.SheetName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

And finally this is partial view:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Paper Specification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Paper Specification</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        @if (ViewBag.sheets_L != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <option>@item.SheetName</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this is no Entity issue but it's Partial View issue.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at `var _sheets = _entity.Sheets.ToList();` and checked if it contains any data?

Comment: You don't need PaperSpecification action at all. Put your partial view in Index view

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pavel in comments replace:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("PaperSpecification", "WorkOrder");
}
```

With

```
@Html.Partial("_SheetSpecificationPartial")
```

In this case you don't need to pass explicitly the model to your partial view. Now you can remove `PaperSpecification` method.